# Run code in loop till result is achieved in python or pyspark

Tags: python, loops, pyspark

I have script like below in `pyspark`.

What I am trying to do here is

```
1) run a query against oracle database and create a data frame.
2) Then want to check if a column is greater than or equal to a constant value.
3) If all records are greater than or equal to then exit the script else run the code in a loop till condition is satisfied.




import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# Spark session builder
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

count_max = 50


def oracle_pull_check():
    df = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@your_aliastns?TNS_ADMIN=path/to/wallet") \
        .option("dbtable", 'table_name or query') \
        .option("user", "user") \
        .option("password", "password") \
        .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
        .load()

    # create column count_limit by checking if count_now greater than or equal to count_max
    df1 = df.withColumn("count_max", f.lit(count_max))\
        .withColumn("count_limit",
                    f.when(f.col("count_now") >= f.col("count_max"), 'Y').otherwise(f.lit('N')))

    # find the count of records where count_limit == N
    df2 = df1.filter(f.col("count_limit") == 'N').count()
    return df2


limit_values = oracle_pull_check()

if limit_values == 0:
    print("count_limit is reached for all fruits")
else:
    # sleep for one minute
    time.sleep(60)
    # then run the oracle_pull_check function again
    limit_values = oracle_pull_check()
    # then check if limit_values == 0 repeat process till limit_values == 0.
    # After 5 iterartions print a custom print statement like "check ran for 5 minutes" "check ran for 10 minutes"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use while loop like below to achieve you result

```
    check_count = True
    counter = 5

    while check_count and counter > 0:
        counter -= 1
        limit_values = oracle_pull_check()
        if limit_values == 0:
            print("count_limit is reached for all fruits")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("count_limit is not reached for all fruits")
            # sleep
            time.sleep(5)
            # then run the oracle_pull_check function again
            limit_values = oracle_pull_check()
            print(limit_values)
            if counter == 0:
                print("While loop failed")
                sys.exit(1)
```